# what bracha do you make on seaweed and algae?

Tags: halacha, blessing, water, vegetables

These two grow on the soil in the ocean. Is the term "adamah" applicable only to the dry land or does it apply to the land in the ocean as well? Note: I am referring to eating just the seaweed itself; not as part of sushi.

Comment: I found no discussion of seaweed in *Halachos of Brochos* (R' Yisroel Pinchos Bodner).  There's a discussion of hydroponically-grown vegetables, but that doesn't seem to apply here.